# Characterizing Dense Subgroups of the Reals

Tags: abstract-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ either dense or has a least positive element?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90177/subgroup-of-mathbbr-either-dense-or-has-a-least-positive-element)

Let $(\mathbb{R},+)$ be the group of Real Numbers under addition. Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that either $H$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ or there is an $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $H=\{ na : n=0, \pm{1},\pm{2},\dots\}$.

I am not able to proceed.

Comment: This is not about analysis.

Comment: I think the title should be 'Characterizing *non-dense* subgroups of R'

Comment: I had to prove this once to solve a *Monthly* problem; it seemed like something that should be well-known, but I never found it in print.  Does anyone know of a reference?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: "Principles of Real Analysis" by Charlambos Aliprantis. This question is somewhere in the first chapter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If there is a smallest positive element, then we are done, since any positive element must be an integer multiple of it, or otherwise we could use a euclidean-type-algorithm to get a positive element with smaller value. (I.e., suppose $a$ is the smallest positive element, and $b$ a   positive element which is not an integer multiple of $a$---keep subtracting copies of $a$ until you get something that is strictly between $0 $ and $a$.)

So assume there is a sequence $a_n$ contained in the group that consists of positive numbers tending to zero. Then the group contains each ${\mathbb{Z} a_n}$. This means that for each $n$, any number in $\mathbb{R}$ is within $|a_n|$ of an element of the group. Since the $|a_n|$ can be small, we find that the group is dense.

Comment: How do you go about your thinking, and what makes you to think about the least element.

Comment: It's a fairly standard trick (cf. the proof that any discrete subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of full rank is a lattice, for instance).