# Subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ either dense or has a least positive element?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let's say $G$ is some additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ that has at least two elements.

From what I understand, $G$ is then either dense in $\mathbb{R}$, or has some least positive element. What is the reason for this?

Comment: See also [Characterizing Dense Subgroups of the Reals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909/characterizing-dense-subgroups-of-the-reals) for a further answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let $a=\inf\{g\in G; g>0\}$. (Note that this set is non-empty and thus $a\ge 0$, $a<\infty$.)

Suppose that $a\notin G$.

This implies that for each $\varepsilon>0$ there is $g\in G$ such that $a<g<a+\varepsilon$. The same argument gives the existence of $g'$ such that $a<g'<g<a+\varepsilon$. Thus we found $h_\varepsilon=g-g'$ which belongs to $G$ and fulfills $0<h_\varepsilon<\varepsilon$.

Now it is relatively easy to see that $\bigcup\limits_{\varepsilon>0}\{z\cdot h_\varepsilon; z\in\mathbb Z\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ and it is subset of $G$.

(If you choose some interval  $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)$, which has length $2\varepsilon$, then it must contain some element of the form $z\cdot h_\varepsilon$, since the distance between two neighboring elements of this form is less than $\varepsilon$.)

---

An analogous claim (or at least one of them - there are other possible generalizations) in higher dimensions would be:

> An additive subgroup of $\mathbb R^n$ is discrete if and only if it is generated by linearly independent vectors $a_1,\dots,a_m\in\mathbb R^n$, $m\le n$.

In the case $n=1$ we get only one generator.

Proof of this claim can be found e.g. in Stewart, Tall: Algebraic Number Theory and Fermat's Last Theorem 6.1 (in Section 6.1 Lattices) and probably in many other texts dealing with [lattices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_%28group%29) in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: I might be naive in pointing this out, but isn't it $h_{\epsilon}=g-g^{'}$ rather than  $h_{\epsilon}=g^{'}-g$?

Comment: Thanks, corrected.

Comment: @gen As I do not want to digress too much from the original question here, I have left a few comments in the [group theory chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/80888/2019/3/2).

Answer (score 36):

Let $G$ be an additive subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that there does not exists the least positive element, i.e. $\inf\{|x|:x\in G-\{0\}\}=0$. Then we can prove that $G$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ as follows: suppose that $y\in\mathbb{R}$, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exist $x\in G$ such that $|x|<\epsilon$. We can assume that $x>0$, otherwise, we can take $-x$ which belongs to $G$ since $G$ is an additive group. Then there exists an integer $n$ such that 
$$nx\leq y<(n+1)x,$$
which implies that 
$$|y-nx|<x<\epsilon,$$
where $nx\in G$ since $G$ is an additive group. This shows that $G$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 12):

I once used this fact to solve a problem in the American Mathematical Monthly.  Here's the proof I gave, which is rather similar to Paul's.

We first show that if $G$ has a limit point, then it is dense.  Fix
  $\epsilon > 0$ and let $y$ be a limit point of $G$.  Choose $x_1, x_2 \in
  G$ with $0 < |{x_1-y}| < \epsilon/2$, and $|{x_2 - y}| < |{x_1 -
  y}|$.  Then $x := x_1 - x_2 \in G$ with $0 < |{x}| < \epsilon$.
  $G$ now contains all integer multiples of $x$, so every interval of
  length at least $\epsilon$ contains an element of $G$.  $\epsilon$
  was arbitrary so $G$ is dense.

As the contrapositive of this, if $G$ is not dense then it has no
  limit points.  In this case, let $a := \inf \{ x \in G, x > 0\}$.  (This set is nonempty since $G$ is nontrivial and hence contains at
  least one positive number.)  Since neither $0$ nor $a$ are limit
  points of $G$, $a > 0$ and $a \in G$.  By construction, $a$ is the least positive element of $G$.  (Moreover, $G$ is generated by $a$.)

For those curious about the Monthly problem, it's #11345, volume 115 number 2, page 166, February 2008:

> **11345.** *Proposed by Roger Cuculière, France.*  Find all nondecreasing functions $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+f(y)) = f(f(x)) + f(y)$ for all real $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Someone mention in [the other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909/characterizing-dense-subgroups-of-the-reals) first chapter of Aliprantis, Burkinshaw: Principles of Real Analysis as a possible reference. Did you find it there? (I did not.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: I didn't look.

Comment: I'm curious which Monthly problem can be solved by using this fact. Can you give a reference? Thank you very much.

Comment: @EricYewenSun: I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

We assume $G$ has no least positive element. Take $x_n \rightarrow 0^+$. Take a decreasing subsequence $(y_n)$ of $(x_n)$.

After each $y_i$, we insert additional terms equal to $y_i - x_j < y_{i+1}$, preserving monotonicity [possible, since we can make $x_j$ as small as we want], until the sum of all these terms exceeds $\frac{1}{i}$. We obtain $(z_i)$.

$S=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (-1)^i z_i$ is a convergent alternating series that is absolutely divergent by comparison with the harmonic series, hence by the [Riemann series theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) we can rearrange terms to make it sum to any real number. Now, taking the partial sums of such a rearrangement, we obtain a sequence tending to any real number. Hence $G$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You have probably a typo $(-)^i$ instead of $(-1)^i$ and $S$ instead of $G$ in the first sentence. Maybe it would be good to mention that $G$ is closed under finite sums, therefore the partial sums $s_n$ are elements of $G$ that converge to $S$. (Someone who is inexperienced might not see right away how your argument implies the density of $G$.)

Comment: Thanks, fixed. I tend to write $(-)$ in my own work, but here it is indeed probably better to stick to $(-1)$.