# Cyclicity of some special subgroup of $(\mathbb R,+)$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

If $H$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbb R,+)$ such that $H\cap[-1,1]$ is finite and contains a positive element then is it true that $H$ is cyclic ?

Comment: You could try to prove the basic: Any subgroup of $\;\Bbb R\;$ is either cyclic or dense in $\;\Bbb R\;$ .  This answers your question at once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discrete subgroups of $(\mathbb{R},+)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2724753/discrete-subgroups-of-mathbbr) or this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90177/subgroup-of-mathbbr-either-dense-or-has-a-least-positive-element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that $H\cap [-1,1]$ is finite. Then, the set contains a least positive element. Let's say $a$ is this element.

**Claim:** $H=\langle a \rangle.$

Suppose, $\exists b\in H$ such that $b$ not in $\langle a\rangle$.

Apply division algorithm and try to get to a contradiction.

Comment: I think this proof doesn't work. Consider $H=2\Bbb{Z}$. In that case, we get $H\cap[-1,1]=\{0\}$.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand the question.

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi: If I am not misunderstanding , neither $b$ nor $a$ should be integers , how do I apply division algorithm ?

Comment: Actually, I shouldn't say **division algorithm**. But note that if there exists such a $b\in H\bigcap[-1,1]$ as in the answer, then of course for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $na<b<(n+1)a$, thus $0<b-na<a$ and this contradicts the minimality of $a$. This looks **somewhat like** the division algorithm.

Comment: I think $a$ should be chosen as 'the least positive element', instead of the 'minimum element'; and your claim should read $H = <a>$

Comment: Yes, my bad! Edited accordingly. :)

Comment: @AnneBauval Hi. I opened the site after a long time, apologies for the delay. I just realised that the first comment made by Hanul Jeon does not satisfy the hypothesis of the question since the intersection does not have a positive element.

Answer (score -1):

1. Suppose that $H$ is not cyclic and it has at least $2$ $\mathbb{Q}$-independent generators $g_1, g_2$.
2. Without loss of generality one of them $g_1 = 1$ (otherwise we can assume subgroup $g_1^{-1}H$ and it isomorphic to $H$). From this we can say that $g_2$ is irrational.
3. Finally, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$ and $ \forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ $nx \neq mx$ (mod $1$) (otherwise $x$ is rational). So all residues $nx$ modulo $1$ are different. Contradiction with fact that $H \cap [-1, 1]$ is finite.

Comment: Point 1 is very incomplete (why does non-cyclicity imply the existence of two such elements?) and the last sentence of point 3 is mysterious. Moreover, the method for the wlog of point 2 is incompatible with the hypothesis $H \cap [-1, 1].$