# If $H$ is a closed subgroup of $G$ then $H=G$ or $H$ is discrete?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, polish-groups

If $G$ is a topological group and $H$ is a closed subgroup, is it the case the $H$ is either discrete or else $H=G$? I see this is true for $G=\mathbb{R}^d$ in [Subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ either dense or has a least positive element?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90177/subgroup-of-mathbbr-either-dense-or-has-a-least-positive-element)

Does the same hold for general $G$? I'm willing to assume $G$ is locally compact, second-countable, Hausdorff (i.e. a Polish group).

Comment: The question you linked to seems to be about dense subgroups?

Comment: @bof Yes I meant to ask something slightly different, but you guys are too good at answering quickly! Stay tuned for my revised question...

Comment: Very no. Closed subgroups needn't be discrete. Examples with Lie groups abound and are very easy to make. For instance, $\Bbb R^k\subset\Bbb R^n$ for $1<k<n$, or $$SO(n)\subset O(n)\subset SL(n, \Bbb R)\subset GL(n,\Bbb R),\textrm{ or}$$ $$SU(n)\subset U(n)\subset GL(n,\Bbb C),\textrm{ or}$$ $$\textrm{unitriangulars}\subset\textrm{upper triangular}\subset GL,$$ or $H\subset H\times K$ where $K$ is another positive dimension Lie group, etc. etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$R$, the real line, is a closed subgroup of $R\times R$, but is not discrete.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}, \cdot )$, which is locally compact and Hausdorff. Then the torus $( \mathbb{T}, \cdot)$ is a non-discrete proper closed subgroup of $(\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}, \cdot )$.