# Is $\mathbb Z[i/2]:=\{f(i/2) : f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x] \}$ dense in $\mathbb C$?

Tags: analysis, polynomials, ring-theory, metric-spaces

Is $\mathbb Z[i/2]:=\{f(i/2) : f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]  \}$ (smallest subring containing $\mathbb Z$ and $i/2$ )  dense in $\mathbb C$ ?

NOTE : $\mathbb Z [i/2] \ne \mathbb Z + \dfrac i2 \mathbb Z $

Comment: $\{\,f(i):f(x)\in{\bf Z}[x]\,\}$ does not contain $i/2$.

Comment: If $f(x)=x$, then $f(i)=i\ne i/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You have $-2(i/2)^2=1/2$ so you can do nested intervals. Just show that $\Bbb Z[1/2]$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ and then proceed to $\Bbb C$.

**Edit:**
We know that a subgroup of $\Bbb R$ has a [least positive element or is dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90177/subgroup-of-mathbbr-either-dense-or-has-a-least-positive-element). Hence as $\Bbb Z[1/2]$ has no minimal positive element it is dense in the reals.

Further if $D\subset k$ is dense, then also $D[x] \subset k[x]$ is dense.

Now if we apply this to
$$ \Bbb Z[i/2] = (\Bbb Z [1/2]) [i] $$
we know $\Bbb Z[i/2]$ is dense in the complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

As $\{m/2^n : m \in \mathbb Z , n \in \mathbb N\} \subseteq \mathbb Z[1/2]$ , so $\mathbb Z[1/2]$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ .

Then since $\mathbb Z[1/2]+i\mathbb Z[1/2] \subseteq \mathbb Z[i/2] \subseteq \mathbb C$ , so $\mathbb Z[i/2]$ is dense in $\mathbb C$