# complex periodic function on the imaginary line

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem Statement**

Find all entire functions such that $f(it)=f(it+i)=f(it+i\sqrt{2})$ for all real $t$.

**My approach:**

Naturally a constant function satisfies the above conditions and thus I thought about trying to prove that any function that satisfies the above conditions must be a constant function.

Liouville's theorem sounds relevant since the function is entire but I can't see a way of proving it must be bounded.

An exercise of a similar nature goes like this:

"prove that if $f(z)$ is entire and doubly periodic, meaning it has $2$ linearly independent (over the reals) periods, then $f(z)$ is a constant"

I do know how to prove the above and it is proven by Liouville's theorem. But I can't seem to replice the proof that $f(z)$ is bounded in my exercise.

Please don't give me a full solution, hints will great :)

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: it would either have to be not differentiable or a constant.

Comment: Identity theorem. But it's also useful to prove that a continuous function $g \colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ with periods $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$ is constant.

Comment: Though he doesn't want full solutions, I guess he wants full hints. ;-)

Comment: See for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136665/for-every-irrational-alpha-the-set-ab-alpha-a-b-in-mathbbz-is-den or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90177/subgroup-of-mathbbr-either-dense-or-has-a-least-positive-element

Comment: Thanks, I understand now :)