# Subgroups of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ are either cyclic or dense

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, quotient-spaces

So I know that subgroups of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ are either isomorphic to $x \mathbb{Z}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, or dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

I don't see how (if?) this descends to the quotient, though.
Denote $G = \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. If $H \leq G$, then by the third iso theorem there is a group $\mathbb{Z} \leq \tilde{H} \leq \mathbb{R}$ such that $H \cong \tilde{H}/\mathbb{Z}$.
How to proceed?
I'm very lost.

---

(Also, from this it supposedly follows that for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the image of 
$$
\phi_x:\mathbb{Z} \to G, \quad n \mapsto nx + \mathbb{Z}
$$
is dense in $G$ if $x$ is irrational. I also don't see this: For any $x$, the image of $\phi_x$ is $x\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}$, is this not cyclic? The above result would then imply that the image is not dense. Somewhere is an error in my thought process.)

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325904/subgroups-of-mathbb-r-are-either-dense-or-cyclic) is the reference for the first statement.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this generalizes to the torus: a line with irrational slope is dense ( exercise in Guillemin and Pollack).