# When will the function be identically zero

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function from $\Bbb R$ to itself.

If $ f(m\pm n\pi)=0$ for all $m,n\in \Bbb Z$ show that $f=O$

I am unable to proceed in this case.

Sorry I couldn't do anything positive to show you all.

I tried with some examples but don't know what to do.

Comment: Hint:  show that for any irrational $\alpha$ the set $\{m+n\alpha\}_{m,n\in \mathbb Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Are $m$ and $n$ supposed to be integers? If not, then you can show that for any $x$, $f(x) = 0$ by picking $m = x, n = 0$.

Comment: How to show that $m + n\pi$ is dense

Comment: That density result comes up a lot in number theory.  As a first step to proving it, prove that it is dense near $0$.  Hint:  if it isn't dense near $0$ then there is a minimal non-zero element $\beta$.  Show that the entire set consists of multiples of $\beta$.  Deduce from that that $\beta$, and therefore $\alpha$, are rational.

Comment: Just to be clear, the statement you are trying to prove will need to use the non-trivial fact that $\pi$ is irrational.  If you replace $\pi$ with, say, $\frac 12$ the claim is false.

Comment: @lulu,will you please explain what is your point in proving dat $m+n\pi$is dense

Comment: If a continuous function is constant on a dense set it is constant (easy exercise).

Comment: @lulu I know that,I am unable to understand how to show that $m+n \pi$ is dense

Comment: Why should we prove dense around 0 only

Comment: The links supplied in the comments to the posted solution are quite thorough.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Here are the relevant facts:

- If $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, then $\mathbb Z + \alpha\mathbb Z=\{m+n\alpha\ : m,n\in \mathbb Z\}$ is an additive subgroup of $\mathbb R$ .
- An additive subgroup of $\mathbb R$ is either cyclic or dense.
- $\mathbb Z + \alpha\mathbb Z$ is cyclic iff $\alpha$ is rational.
- $\pi$ is irrational.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136665/for-every-irrational-alpha-the-set-ab-alpha-a-b-in-mathbbz-is-den and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90177/subgroup-of-mathbbr-either-dense-or-has-a-least-positive-element for instance