# Discreteness of $\{ a+b\sqrt2 \mid a,b \in \Bbb N \}$ in $\Bbb R$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-number-theory

How to prove that $\{ a+b\sqrt2 \mid a,b \in \Bbb N \}$ is discrete in $\Bbb R$?

If I sum over $\Bbb Z$ instead of over $\Bbb N$, it becomes dense, which is quite confusing to me.

Also, when I plot the points, they appear to become denser as I go to the right, which leads me to wonder if the set is really discrete.

Comment: What do you mean by discrete? Every point of it is open in itself?

Comment: @pisco125 yes, that is what it means.

Comment: Then you basically answered the question below. Simply choose a small neighborhood which evades all those finite points.

Comment: @pisco125 I didn't know that the points are finite. Of course I answered the question below, or else I wouldn't have posted it as an answer.

Comment: See also the answers at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73262/proving-that-mn-sqrt2-is-dense-in-r), and at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909/characterizing-dense-subgroups-of-the-reals).

Comment: @DietrichBurde but my set is hardly a subgroup.

Comment: Ah, I see, I am sorry. But the part "If I sum over $\Bbb Z$ instead of over $\Bbb N$, it becomes dense, which is quite confusing to me." is covered by the duplicate at least.

Comment: See more specifically [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2130828/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque Again, that question is about $\Bbb Z[\sqrt2]$ not $\Bbb N[\sqrt2]$. What is the criterion of duplicates?

Answer (score -1):

It is discrete, as for every $N$ there are only finitely many elements from the set less than $N$, because for every $a+b\sqrt2 < N$, we know tha $a+b<N$, but there are only at most $N(N+1)/2$ possible pairs of $(a,b)$ with $a+b < N$, so the number of elements from the set that are less than $N$ is also finite.